# In what all ways can I run a health check on my Salesforce instance?

Tags: bestpractice

In what all ways can I run a health check on my SF instance so that I improve the operational health of the overall instance and I minimize the technical debt. I know that we can run Salesforce Optimizer on our org's metadata are there any other ways to gauge the health of the system?

Answer (score 1):

you can run a HealthCheck on your org and if you use Communities (Experiences as of Spring 21), you can also HealthCheck these. You can use the SFDC baseline or import your own if your company has a security baseline in place.

Some of the items the tool will find can be fixed for you. Be careful to  UAT in a sandbox as many security settings will have breaking impact on your org or integrations. You may need to create a list and prioritize refactoring in order to comply with all security settings.

Here is info on the HealthCheck tool...

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_health_check.htm